# Javascript Mouse Position location?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

Im trying to build a game the objective is to hit the enimies that come out from the water by clicking on them, I have been trying to get a water jet come out of a statues mouth (which has sort of been succesful and can be seen here: http://mckenziedave.co.uk/client_files/html5_game/) however it is slighty off, I believe this is because of the game being within the game screen (div id="gamefiled"). How can I take this into factor within the JS script (script below)

```
var flame,
    sourceX = 780,
    sourceY = 215;

window.onload = function() {
  flame = document.getElementById('flame');
  game.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var targetX = e.pageX,
          targetY = e.pageY,
          deltaX = targetX - sourceX,
          deltaY = targetY - sourceY,
          rad = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX),
          deg = rad * (180 / Math.PI),
          length = Math.sqrt(deltaX*deltaX+deltaY*deltaY);   

      fire(deg,length);
  }, false);
};

function fire(deg,length) {
    flame.style.opacity = 1;
    flame.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)'
    flame.style.width = length + 'px';
    setTimeout(function() {
       flame.style.opacity = 0;
    },780);
};
```

Cheers

Comment: I've answered this once already, why did you delete and re-ask the same thing?

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand you answer and didnt get any replies, so thought id repost with the example etc

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine the offset of the div id="gamefiled", relative to the browser window in your click event and substract it from the mouse position.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried playing your game and I clicked some crabs but no hits. This is probably a math error since players play the game on different resolutions on different devices. Not to mention the pixel size problem where PCs, tablets and phones don't have universal pixel sizes.

Have you tried obtaining coordinates like this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clientx.asp

```
var x = event.clientX;
var y = event.clientY;
```

For drawing lines (precise) I'd recommend something like a Bresenham algorithm but this is just my opinion.

You can also try a much more simple solution like this:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_lineto.asp

You can use canvas for drawing lines like so:

```
function drawLine (x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end) {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x_start, y_start);
    ctx.lineTo(x_end, y_end);
    //set line width and color
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

I rewrote this solution from w3schools.com.